# Ionic2: Update modified plugins

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2

I've imported a plug-in into my Ionic 2 project and made some changes to it to see if that would solve a problem I had with it. Is there a way to update that plug-in's implementation in the added platforms?

on that note, is there a way to make my own plug-in without having to publish it on Cordova?

Comment: Could you please let us know the name of the plugin ?

Comment: It's `cordova-plugin-sim`. I'm adding line state and connection states to the ios and WP platforms. Linestate is a boolean on if the phone is in a call or not, connections state is an integer telling if the phone has a GSM connection, and if it's roaming or not. Next up is adding subscription for notification on a change of the parameters (MCC, MNC, Line state and connection state). The problem is that to get ionic to "publish" the modification I make to the plugin to the platforms, I have to remove and add the platforms.